# Rpmbuild - setting name of created .rpm

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild

I've been trying to find out what's the easiest way to set a fixed filename during `rpm` creation. Can it be set somewhere in .spec file or as `rpmbuild` parameter? The default name depends on version and release number. Name of my rpm has to be always the same.

thanks

sync

Answer (score 19):

Yes, override the `%_rpmfilename` macro. The default value according to my `rpm --showrc` is:

```
%%{ARCH}/%%{NAME}-%%{VERSION}-%%{RELEASE}.%%{ARCH}.rpm
```

So, you could add the following (or similar) to the top of your .spec file:

```
%define _rpmfilename %%{NAME}.%%{OS}.%%{ARCH}.rpm
```

Comment: caveat: you should have a _very_ good reason for doing this per RPM, if you really want to change the naming scheme and make it incompatible with your distro (ie you are packaging for your own distro with different naming standards), redefine _rpmfilename "upstream" in the system rpm macros